# Can I push my code into my private server?

Tags: reactjs, github, cpanel

I have a question, I made a react app and I wanna upload my code into my server, I have the Git Version Control from my CPanel but I wanna know if I can push my code directly into my server  without using GitHub repo, is that possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use [filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) or sftp protocol.